# How to convert XML webservice output to Json using Express.js & Backbone.js

Tags: xml, json, node.js, express

I am a newbie into Node.js

I have come across many XML 2 Json Conversions, None of them satisfied my needs up to the mark. Out of all this conversion supports, i get one or the other error as something is missing and don't support to the version.

Here is my code :

```
 exports.index = function(req, res){    
   var request = require('request');
   var url = 'xml-output-throwing-url';

     request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
           res.json(body);
        }
     });
 };
```

This throws output of rendering the xml as : 
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"..someurl...">..Output.."

Which is enclosed by "". Now i am trying to convert this output to json and render this from backbone.js and make this presentation in a neat way. But the output will be empty when i am using JSON.stringify(this.model) in the render function.

What am I doing wrong here?

How to achieve this?

My doubts are : Do I need to convert xml to json from server side i.e from express.js or backbone. Which is best among this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json sounds like a good place to start.

```
var parser = require('xml2json');

// ...

exports.index = function(req, res){    
   var request = require('request');
   var url = 'xml-output-throwing-url';

     request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
           var result = parser.toJson(body, {
              object: false,
              reversible: false,
              coerce: true,
              sanitize: true,
              trim: true,
              arrayNotation: false
           });
           res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           res.send(result);
        }
    });
};
```

Note that I use `res.send` instead of `res.json` because `res.json` converts whatever you give it (a string, in this case!) to JSON. This would result in double escaping. Using `res.send` with the appropriate content type avoids this.

You could use `object: true` to get an actual JS object out of `parser.toJson`, but that would mean extra work on the server: The parser would build an object and `res.json` would immediately serialize it again. That's not necessary.

Converting on the server side has advantages, since XML handling on the client does not work as well and seamlessly as JSON handling.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable feedback. I am keep trying this xml2json from past 2 days. 

But i get this [ERROR](http://imgur.com/n470r5A)

I have tried to set environmental variable for python as well and restarted my system as well. But still not working. Please assist with this..

Comment: Well, `node-xml2json` has a dependency to `node-expat`. Have you installed that module?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get this [Error](http://i1mgur.com/71By9bR) when i try to install on which u suggested . 
And I have worked on many with npms with in this couple of days. I keep getting errors like : "No repository field". Does that mean its still in progress or removed or in the stage of development or am i doing wrong in the installation :P

Comment: `node-expat` requires Python in turn. ;) If you don't want to install Python just because of this (and maybe that's really overkill), try another XML-to-JS converter. https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml2js would be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks i managed to get this done with the combination of efforts. It killed me for last two days. Last but not the least, the output is been truncated or toggled and displayed as objects for the child nodes. So how to expand this and see the clear result and how to handle this from backbone. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. But it starts to get out of the scope of this thread anyway, so maybe you ask a new question that contains your current code and issues?